# Electric Field Intensity

Tags: electric-fields, intensity

The electric field intensity everywhere is
$E=E_0-j$ (y-direction) in vacuum (say $E_0=5$).

if you have an infinite-perfect conductor starting at the $x \geq 4$ plane and $x < 4$ is  vacuum. What is $E$ in the vacuum and in the conductor?

My initial thought is that $E$ is $E_0=5$ outside and 0 inside given that Electric Field Intensity is 0 inside a conductor?

It seems like a trick question for a problem i am working on, but just want to be sure. Am i missing something?

Comment: Is it how can you subtract j (position) from E. Or is it the case that E is in y-direction?

Comment: E is in the y-direction. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Then you are right. E is 5 outside and 0 inside.

Comment: Thanks for the reply much appreciated.